# Substitute to fortify to plot a map with sf package

Tags: r, ggplot2, geospatial, spatial

I want to plot a map. In the early times, everything was OK, but with the absence of `rgdal` and `maptools`, some functions don't seem to have substitutes. For me it is the case of `fortify`; I try `tidy` and others functions without success.

```
In my example:

#----------------------------------------------------
# Map representation
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

url <- "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/hrbrmstr/91ea5cc9474286c72838/raw/f3fde312c9b816dff3994f39f2bcda03209eff8f/continents.json"
stop_for_status(GET(url, write_disk("continents.json")))
continents <- geojson_sf("continents.json")
continents.f <- continents[continents$CONTINENT %in% c("North America", "Central America", "South America"),]
continents_map <- fortify(continents.f, region="CONTINENT")


gg <- ggplot() # the base map
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=continents_map, map=continents_map,
                    aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=id, group=group),
                    fill="#ffffff", color="black", size=0.15) +
                    lims(x = c(-110, -20), y = c(-60, 20))
gg 
#---------------------------------------------------- 

Error in `geom_map()`:
! `map` must have the columns `x`, `y`, and `id`
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Please, any help with it?

Comment: Add to that the problem that `ggplot2::fortify` might be deprecated in the future since the author(s) recommend instead the use of the `broom` package.

Comment: Where is `geojson_sf` defined?

Comment: While `fortify()` is exposed to users, there shouldn't be a reason to call it directly. When passing data to a plot or layer, it gets `fortify()`'ed automatically. It mostly exists as a data formatting S3 method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just load data with `read_sf()` from `sf` package and the `fortify()` is not necessary. It is recommended to use `geom_sf()` to plot map when the geojson data is loaded.

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

continents <- read_sf("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/hrbrmstr/91ea5cc9474286c72838/raw/f3fde312c9b816dff3994f39f2bcda03209eff8f/continents.json")
continents.f <- continents[continents$CONTINENT %in% c("North America", "Central America", "South America"),]

ggplot(data = continents.f) +
  geom_sf(fill="#ffffff", color="black", size=0.15) +
  lims(x = c(-110, -20), y = c(-60, 20))


# add some values to fill
continents.f$test <- 1:nrow(continents.f)
ggplot(data = continents.f) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = test)) +
  lims(x = c(-110, -20), y = c(-60, 20))
```